# Network monitoring in PhantomJSDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to figure out how to log network traffic when running PhantomJSDriver using Selenium in C#. Online search result keep pointing to js code for phantomjs so there has got to be a way to do this.

Comment: Use a proxy? That's the standard response for such a thing.

Comment: Are you using Selenium to initiate the web calls and perform the client actions?